# Retrieve argument position when multiple args are provided sequentially with Python argparse

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

Here is my function argument prototype: 
`./myfunction.py --poi_type1 loc1 --poi_type2 loc2 --poi_type1 loc3`

To understand the context, POI (poi_type1 & 2) are points of interst of different nature (type1 is garden, type2 is statue for example). I would like to generate a graph in return which connect the different POI type (business logic behind is not the purpose of my request). The graph must take into account the position  of the POI argument within the command line , and how I will build the graph will depend on the poi_type (1 or 2).

It is important to note that the user can provide as many POI as he wants, and for each POI he should tell if it is a `poi_type1` or `poi_type2`.

What I started first to collect the argument given by the user is the following:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='generate graph', formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('--poi_type1', nargs=1, action='append', type=check_target)
parser.add_argument('--poi_type2', nargs=1, action='append', type=not_supported)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

My problem is that I don't know in which order the argument are provided by the user if the user provides both `poi_type1` and `poi_type2`.

For example:

```
./myfunction.py --poi_type1 loc1 --poi_type2 loc2 --poi_type1 loc3
```

Returns the same results as

```
./myfunction.py --poi_type2 loc1 --poi_type1 loc2 --poi_type1 loc3
```

I do not know how to adapt my script so that it works as I want... any idea? Thank you!

Comment: parse `sys.argv` directly.

Comment: Define a '--poi' with `nargs=2`.  User would enter '--poi type1 loc1 --poi type2 loc2 --poi type1 loc3',